# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource while calling a .NET web api from React app

Tags: reactjs, .net, asp.net-core, cors, asp.net-core-webapi

I have created a .Net Core 7 Web API and I'm trying to call it from a React app. I've added CORS policy in my backend code in the following manner -

```
builder.Services.AddCors(p => p.AddPolicy("corspolicy", builder =>
{
    builder
    .WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000/")
    //.AllowAnyOrigin()
    .AllowAnyMethod()
    .AllowAnyHeader();
}));

app.UseCors("corspolicy");
```

However, I'm still getting the following error in my React app when I log the response -

```
Access to fetch at 'https://localhost:7063/api/CloneAPI' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Access to fetch at 'https://localhost:7063/api/CloneAPI' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

If I allow all origins in my backend code like this -

```
builder.Services.AddCors(p => p.AddPolicy("corspolicy", builder =>
{
    builder
    //.WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000/")
    .AllowAnyOrigin()
    .AllowAnyMethod()
    .AllowAnyHeader();
}));

app.UseCors("corspolicy");
```

then I am able to fetch all the data successfully. However, I don't want to allow all origins due to safety reasons. Can someone please help me out on why I am getting this error   despite setting up CORS and the URLs are correct too?

My frontend code -

```
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://localhost:7063/api/CloneAPI")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        setPosts(data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err.message);
      });
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to [Enable Cross-Origin Requests (CORS) in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-7.0)：

> Note: The specified URL must not contain a trailing slash (/). If the
> URL terminates with /, the comparison returns false and no header is
> returned.

Please remove the trailing slash in `.WithOrigins()`, just configure like:

```
.WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000")
```

then you can access your endpoint correctly without Cors error.

Comment: Hi @coderfromhell, Have you solved this issue now?

Comment: Thanks @Xinran Shen, it is working for me. Sorry for marking this answer as correct so late. I thought I had already done that.